# very basic c++ code....but don't understand

Tags: c++

I am just a beginner and don't know why these two are different. If someone can explain, I will really appreciate it! thanks!

What is the difference between
1)

```
void Image::adjustbrightness(int r, int g, int b)
{
    for (size_t x = 0; x < (*this).width(); x++)
    {                   
        if (r+f(x)->red <= 0)
         f(x)->red = 0;
        else if(r+f(x)->red >= 255)         
         f(x)->red = 255;
        else
         f(x)->red = r + f(x)->red; 
    }
}
```

and 
2)

```
void Image::adjustbrightness(int r, int g, int b)
{
    for (size_t x = 0; x < (*this).width(); x++)
    {                   
        f(x)->red = r + f(x)->red;
        if f(x)->red <= 0)
         f(x)->red = 0;
        else if (f(x)->red>=255)            
         f(x)->red = 255;
        else

    }
}
```

Comment: The second one doesn't compile because the eleventh line has ben ripped off ?

Answer (score 1):

The first one is incorrect in behaviour, the second one is incorrect in syntax :)

What I think the behaviour should be is to increase or decrease the brightness of the image pixels by the provided value `r`. A pixel can have a value between `0` and `255`.

Your first version tries to do that, but fails to keep the value exactly within the right range `0-255` *after* it adjusts the brightness.

Your second version does it better. It first tries to adjust the brightness, then bring the value into the right range `0-255`. However, there is code missing on line 11.

The correct one should be:

```
void Image::adjustbrightness(int r, int g, int b)
{
    for (size_t x = 0; x < (*this).width(); x++)
    {   
        int adjustedRed = r + f(x)->red;                

        if (adjustedRed < 0)
          adjustedRed = 0;
        else if (adjustedRed > 255)            
          adjustedRed = 255;

        f(x)->red = adjustedRed;

        // above 8 lines can also be replaced by: 
        // f(x)->red = std::min(255, std::max(0, r + f(x)->red));

        // also, you will need to do the same with g(reen) and b(lue):
        // auto pixel = f(x);
        // pixel->red = std::min(255, std::max(0, r + pixel->red));
        // pixel->green = std::min(255, std::max(0, g + pixel->green));
        // pixel->blue = std::min(255, std::max(0, b + pixel->blue));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely because the `red` member of whatever `f(x)` returns is an `unsigned char`, which is common for RGB colouring.

The range of values for an 8 bit unsigned char, is from 0 to 255. When you assign something bigger or smaller than that to it, the value overflows and wraps around.

This means that in the second example, your if test will never be true and the (missing) else clause will always be run. This is because `f(x)->red` < 0 can never be true. Your compiler may have warned you of this.

The reason the first example works is that the expressions are converted to `int` because `r` is an int. This means that `r + f(x)->red` can be < 0 as it is an integer expression, not an unsigned char.

A version of your second example that works would store the intermediate result in an integer, which would then let the comparisons work properly:

```
void Image::adjustbrightness(int r, int g, int b)
{
    for (size_t x = 0; x < (*this).width(); x++)
    {                   
        int newR = r + f(x)->red;
        if (newR <= 0)
            f(x)->red = 0;
        else if (newR >= 255)            
            f(x)->red = 255;
        else
            f(x)->red = newR;
    }
}
```

Of course, all this assumes `f(x)->red` is an unsigned char, which is the reason why you should include such information in your original question.

Answer (score 0):

for your code. you can simple understand like this: `1 pixel` in `RGB` will be encoded with `3 bytes`. `1 byte` for `red`, `1 byte` for `green` and last `1 byte` for `blue`. because `1 byte = 8 bit`, so max value is `2^8 = 256`. but it started from `0`, so the range of variable will be `0 -> 255`.

in your code, they are have checking variable of color, they are can't more than 255 or less than 0.

with  `2)`, same i explain above, may be `f(x)->red` is only `1 byte`, so you need check value before change.

this is example

```
void Image::adjustbrightness(int r, int g, int b)
{
    for (size_t x = 0; x < (*this).width(); x++)
    {   
        f(x)->red = std::min(255, std::max(0, r + f(x)->red));
    }
}
```